# Generate 4 random values from an array, but no repeating values

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array that holds countries. I need to figure out how to take three values from the array, and the 4th value needs to be the right answer.**

The answer choices (as radio buttons) need to be random and not repeated, but also contain the right answer and place it at a random location.

```
randomImage[0] = "Colombia";
randomImage[1] = "Argentina";
randomImage[2] = "Bolivia";
randomImage[3] = "Brazil";
randomImage[4] = "Paraguay";
randomImage[5] = "Venezuela";
randomImage[6] = "Ecuador";
randomImage[7] = "Peru";
randomImage[8] = "Chile";
randomImage[9] = "Uruguay";
```

I am using this random variable called numb to show answers randomly from the same array as below, however, the right answer does not always show up.

```
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length);
    var numb = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.length);
    if ((numb == 9) || (numb == 0)) {
        numb = 4;
    }
    else if ((numb == 8) || (numb == 1)) {
        numb = 6;
    }
```

This is how I am showing my answers:

```
function getQuestions(rand) {

    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = '<div><label>' + answers[rand] + '<input id= "answer1" name = "ans" type = "radio" onclick="getResults()" value = "' + answers[rand] + '"></label></div>' +
        '<div><label>' + answers[rand + 1] + '<input id= "answer2" name="ans" type="radio" onclick="getResults()" value = "' + answers[rand + 1] + '"></label></div>' +
        '<div><label>' + answers[rand - 1] + '<input id= "answer3" name="ans" type="radio" onclick="getResults()" value = "' + answers[rand - 1] + '"></label></div>' +
        '<div><label>' + answers[rand + 2] + '<input id= "answer4" name="ans" type="radio" onclick="getResults()" value = "' + answers[rand + 2] + '"></label></div>' +
        '<div><label>None of the above<input id= "answer5" name="ans" type="radio" onclick="getResults()" value="None of the above"></label></div></p>';
}
```

Comment: if u save country map with country name, e.g. `Argentina.png` , u can extract country name from it (this is your answer), then randomly get other three  options using your random function. Then Dynamically generate radio buttons with above values and you will have your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is:

> "How to take three values from the array, and the 4th value needs to
> be the right answer."

Assuming that you know where is the right answer.

Here is a simple solution:

```js
var options = new Set() //Set allows you to store unique values.
options.add(rightAnswerIndex); //add the right answer to the options
while (options.size < 4){
    options.add(getRandomNumber()) //use your code to get random number here
}
```

So, just implement `getRandomNumber()` as a function and you are good to go.

With this solution, the right answer will be the first in this set, if it's important to have it in the 4th place, you can just replace it.

Convert your set to an array, and access the index you need:

```js
var arrayFromSet = [...options];
var correctAnswer = arrayFromSet[0];
```

Comment: I appreciate it! So would I refer to options as an array? So if I were to showcase the right answer in the first position could I do options[0]?

Comment: @AlexMartinez You will need to convert it to an array, I've updated my answer to show that.
Another way to convert is using `Array.from()`